# HTML button anchor link

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

Thanks in advance for your help.

I want three buttons to anchor link to a single location (contact form) on a one page website.

Button 1 works, but the other two display missing pages or wrong url.

This is the code:

BUTTON 1:

CONTACT ME TODAY

BUTTON 2:

text hereGET IN  TOUCH

BUTTON 3:

text hereCONTACT ME TODAY

LINKED LOCATION:

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code here

Comment: The button which works:

 <a class="button button_large button_stroke_custom button_js" href="#get-in-touch"  style=" border-color:#ffffff !important; color:#ffffff;"><span class="button_label">Get Your FREE Quote</span></a>

Comment: The second button, doesn't work:

<a class="button button_large button_stroke_custom button_js" href="#get-in-touch" style=" border-color:#ff9cba !important; color:#ff9cba;"><span class="button_label">CONTACT ME TODAY</span></a>

Comment: The third button, doesn't work:

 <a class="button button_large button_stroke_custom button_js" href="get-in-touch" style=" border-color:#ffffff !important; color:#ffffff;"><span class="button_label">CONTACT ME TODAY</span></a>

Comment: Links to:

<section id="get-in-touch">

Comment: I just added a "#" before the tags: #get-in-touch and the buttons work.

How can I make it scroll smoothly please?